# Processing.getInstanceById(id); works with one function, undefined for another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, processing

Following http://processingjs.org/articles/PomaxGuide.html for using Processing sketches on webpages, one of my functions utilizes this perfectly:

```
function drawSomething() {

  // some calculations

  var pjs = Processing.getInstanceById('canvasID');
  var number = 5 // placeholder result of calculations
  pjs.drawText(number);
}
```

Yet with another function, drawSomethingElse, the same pjs variable definition logs:

```
TypeError: pjs is undefined
```

All the code is wrapped in docReady, and drawSomething(); is called when the page loads:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // do lots of stuff

  drawSomethingElse();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scope in javascript works like this. If you declare a `var` or `function` inside another function it's only visible inside this function

```
function outerScope(){
   var outerVariable = "is defined in outer scope";
   function innerScope(){
      var innerVariable = "is defined in inner scope";
      console.log(outervariable); //innerScope can see outerVariable (through a closure)
   }
   console.log(innerVariable) //=undefined outerScope can't see innerVariable
   console.log(outerVariable) //outerScope can still see outerVariable
}
console.log(outerScope) //= function, global scope can see outerScope
console.log(outerVariable) //=undefined but global scope can't see inside outerScope
console.log(innerScope) //= undefined, therefore it can't see innerScope
console.log(innerVariable) //=undefined and of course not into inner scope
```

This is true for all functions, including jQuery functions, they are no exception to this rule. So that's why you have to define a `var` in the scope you want the scope "layer" you want to use it. And to not pollute the global scope you wrap things into these anonymous functions, just to add a scope "layer"

This model always applies, no matter how many layers you add. You will always be able to understand the behavior. (btw **always** check all the things with console.log you are unsure about, it helps to track down bugs. the more precise you can answer what is wrong with your solution the better you know how to fix it)

Adapting what you know about scopes and since you didn't define `Processing` in the current scope you know it therefore **must** be in global scope, means you can open your browser console and just `console.log(Processing)` and maybe call the method `Processing.getInstanceById()` yourself in the console a few times. Maybe it's not the canvas id, maybe it's the name of your sketch that defined the name of the instance. Try it out.

Since you now know that your .pde sketch isn't loaded by the time you want to get the instance via javascript, you have a few options. The easiest would be to make the sketch part of the document, so the $(document).ready() only fires and execute your javascript when both, processing and the sketch are loaded.

Usually processing checks the custom `data-processing-sources` attribute on the canvas and sends a asynchronous request for the files (your sketch). But since it's asynchronous it's not part of your document loading, so the document is ready but your sketch isn't.

If you instead put the sketch code in a script tag inside the document the document won't be ready until it's loaded. You also need to set the mime type or the browser will think this is javascript and throw an error. It doesn't change anything else, it's just another way of setting up your Processing Sketch.

```
<script type="text/processing" data-processing-target="canvasID"> 
    //your sketch code
</script>
<canvas id="canvasID"></canvas>
```

And for you to still be able to load your sketch externally here comes the slightly more confusing 3rd way to set up your sketch. Remove the whole script tag and your sketch.

Skip the data-processing-target and data-processing-sources attributes, and instead of `pjs = Processing.getInstanceById` write

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "yourSketch.pde");
    xhr.onload = function(){
        var code = xhr.response;
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasID")
         pjs = new Processing(canvas,code);
         //rest of your code
   }
   xhr.send();
});
```

Note: This technique won't work if you view your website locally from the file:// protocol

Comment: This is a great outline, thanks.. By this explanation though, the pjs definition is an outerVariable, and the drawText() function is an outerScope function.. What might be the reason pjs is logged as undefined?

Comment: If pjs is undefined at the point where you define it, then you know the problem is in `Processing.getInstanceById('canvasID');` maybe wrong canvasID? Test it with `document.getElementById("canvasId")` Maybe at the point of execution Processing isn't done initializing and there is no instance jet?

Comment: Processing isn't done initialzing.. Is there a way to preload the .pde file, to make sure it's loaded before anything else?

Comment: plenty. the easiest would be to put your pde in a inline script tag inside the html and set `<script data-processing-target="canvasId">`  on the script instead of data-processing-source +fileName on the canvas

Comment: Do I need a type for that? And how does the particular canvas connect to this? do I need to continue to call data-processing-target on the actual canvas

Comment: this way it should be loaded when your jQuery document ready executes the javascript part. You still use the `$(document).ready` wrapper, right? (wait i update the answer)

Comment: Yes, doc.ready is still the wrapper.. really appreciate all of this

Comment: Many thanks.. Last question: can I still reference an external .pde this way? Or does it have to all be inline..

Comment: Ah snap, all the code is local right now.. Is there a method for local + external that maybe looks like this: `<script type="text/processing" src="../canvsID.pde" data-processing-target="canvasID"></script>` and 
`var pjs = Processing.getInstanceById('canvasID');`

Comment: and by local, I mean localhost:4200.. am using node.js, so would the client-side XMLHttpRequest work?

Comment: ah jeah nice Node.js <3 yes that would work, only the file:// is affected by the additional security restrictions since otherwise people tricking you into opening a website locally would basically be able to real all your files.

Comment: yehh, node! Does the $(document).ready(function(){//everything}); replace the //rest of your code

Comment: not really, theoretically the sketch -could- be loaded before the canvas or processing exist. Better wrap all of it in `$(document).ready` to be safe

Comment: now have some debugging to do, but the pjs seems to rendering perfectly! Many, many thanks

Answer (score 1):

pjs scope is drawSomething function  for using it in different function change your code like this

```
(function() {
  var pjs = Processing.getInstanceById('canvasID');
  function drawSomething() {
    var number = 5 // placeholder result of calculations
    pjs.drawText(number);
  }

  function someotherfunction() {
     drawSomething();
  }
}());
```

now you can use pjs anywhere in this anon function

Comment: yeh, had tried that too.. for some reason that logs undefined for both calls!?

Comment: wrap your code in an anonymous function, see my modified code

Comment: This looks good, thanks, though how would I call drawSomething() from within another function?

Comment: thought to run the anon function at the start of drawSomething() with return pjs; but that didn't work..

Comment: all your code should be in this anon function see updated code

Comment: (@JeetendraChauhan `var pjs` isn't in global scope when you wrap it, that's the whole point of wrapping it :) But it's out of the function scope. Quick explain: Every `var` you declare inside a function exists only inside this function.

Comment: @Winchestro yes you are right,it's scope is anon function, so every function in this scope(anon) have right to use pjs variable

Comment: Should have been more specific.. drawSomething is called outright in `$(document).ready(function(){ /*lots of stuff..*/ drawSomething();}` so putting that in the anon fun doesn't run... any other suggestions? ..am updating the post to be more accurate

Comment: it should make any difference.

Comment: @Winchestro should everything then be wrapped in `$(document).ready(function(){ (function() { //everything  }()); ;}`